# Given a wsdl will generating webservice client using different methods generate different code?

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, axis

Suppose I have wsdl file as below

```
<definitions name="HelloService"
   targetNamespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
   xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
   xmlns:tns="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <message name="SayHelloRequest">
      <part name="firstName" type="xsd:string"/>
   </message>

   <message name="SayHelloResponse">
      <part name="greeting" type="xsd:string"/>
   </message>

   <portType name="Hello_PortType">
      <operation name="sayHello">
         <input message="tns:SayHelloRequest"/>
         <output message="tns:SayHelloResponse"/>
      </operation>
   </portType>

   <binding name="Hello_Binding" type="tns:Hello_PortType">
      <soap:binding style="rpc"
         transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <operation name="sayHello">
         <soap:operation soapAction="sayHello"/>
         <input>
            <soap:body
               encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
               namespace="urn:examples:helloservice"
               use="encoded"/>
         </input>

         <output>
            <soap:body
               encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
               namespace="urn:examples:helloservice"
               use="encoded"/>
         </output>
      </operation>
   </binding>

   <service name="Hello_Service">
      <documentation>WSDL File for HelloService</documentation>
      <port binding="tns:Hello_Binding" name="Hello_Port">
         <soap:address
            location="http://www.examples.com/SayHello/" />
      </port>
   </service>
</definitions>
```

If we generate web service client code using Apacje Axis, Apache CXF 1.0
or wsimport. Will the generated code differ (Not including comments)? Generated class structure or number of classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the generated code will be different. CXF und wsimport share JAXB XJC as common part, but overall you cannot use it as one to one replacement.